# ordering the results of a query as specified in the where clause

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `QuotesTable` - primary key is `quotesid`.

I have this `sql-statement`:

```
 select * from QuotesTable where quotesid in (103,7,16,50,41,80,67,64)
```

This returns me the result in the following order:

```
 7
 16
 41
 .........
 103 and so on.
```

but I need the results in the following order as specified in the query (103,7,16,50,41,80,67,64) as:

```
 103,
 7
 16
 .......
 64 and so on.
```

Is there a way to achieve this one?

Comment: Do you have an id column on the table that reflects the order?  Or maybe  consider adding an order column in the table for the correct order? What determines that random looking ordering?

Comment: the id column is quotesid which is the primary key.

Comment: I don't think you get what I mean, you said you need it in this order `103,7,16,50,41,80,67,64` what does that actually mean? generally you would have an order column in your database, so that you can simply order by that in this situation.

Comment: This is my requirement. I need this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from QuotesTable where quotesid in (103,7,16,50,41,80,67,64)
order by case quotesid when 103 then 1
                       when  7  then 2
                       when 16  then 3
                       when 50  then 4
                       when 41  then 5
                       when 80  then 6
                       when 67  then 7
                       when 64  then 8
         end
```

If those values grow then you can create a table in database:

```
create table QuotesOrderingTable(quotesid int, orderid int)
go
```

fill it with appropriate values:

```
insert into QuotesOrderingTable values
(103, 1),
(7, 2),
(16, 3),
(50, 4),
(41, 5),
(80, 6),
(67, 7),
(64, 8),
(..., 9),
(..., 10),
...
```

and then use it to order by:

```
select qt.* from QuotesTable qt
join QuotesOrderingTable qot on qt.quotesid = qot.quotesid
where qt.quotesid in (103,7,16,50,41,80,67,64)
order by qot.orderid
```

Comment: this works but isn't other workaround to achieve the same result? What if I need to work with 100 records, the query will become large isn't?

Comment: @Venkat, no this is the simplest. You should order.

Comment: @Venkat:- No this should be the easiest one!

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri:- Good one! +1

Comment: +1 for creating a table, That case statement will become very nasty over time should you add more quotes.

Comment: is this a QuotesOrderingTable - temp table. Please clarify? Please rewrite your query in order to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is doing it like this:

```
SELECT 1, * FROM QuotesTable WHERE quotesid = 103 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, * FROM QuotesTable WHERE quotesid = 7 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, * FROM QuotesTable WHERE quotesid = 16 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, * FROM QuotesTable WHERE quotesid = 50 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, * FROM QuotesTable WHERE quotesid = 41 UNION ALL
SELECT 6, * FROM QuotesTable WHERE quotesid = 80 UNION ALL
SELECT 7, * FROM QuotesTable WHERE quotesid = 67 UNION ALL
SELECT 8, * FROM QuotesTable WHERE quotesid = 64
ORDER BY 1
```

Not the prettiest, but atleast you aren't repeating the WHERE clause

Another variation, which looks a bit nicer:

```
SELECT * FROM QuotesTable q
JOIN (SELECT 1 ordering, 103 quotesid UNION ALL
      SELECT 2         , 7 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3         , 16 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4         , 50 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5         , 41 UNION ALL
      SELECT 6         , 80 UNION ALL
      SELECT 7         , 67 UNION ALL
      SELECT 8         , 64) o ON o.quotesid = q.quotesid
ORDER BY o.ordering
```

Comment: It will work, you eliminated repeating in order clause, but instead you are repeating selects with unions and this is much much worse.

Comment: it would be interesting to compare, as it isn't selecting on a physical table, and you would assume that the number of rows in QuotesTable is much larger than 8